# Kendo Grid Popup Editor - Razor ForEach - List is null

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Sample from RegistrationModel

```
public int Status      {get; set;}
public string Batteries    {get; set;}   
public List<Batteries> BatteriesList     {get; set;}
```

Sample from Grid

```
Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("EditRegistration"))
```

Sample from popup editor template

```
<h2>Batteries</h2>
@{
   if(Model.BatteriesList != null)
   {
    <ul>
        @foreach(var x in Model.BatteriesList)
        {
        <li>x.Selection</li>
        }
    </ul>
   }
}
```

1. Model.BatteriesList is always null when the popup renders on-screen.
2. I know the BatteriesList is filled with data. The other fields in my Editor Template (Status,Batteries)show data in popup.

Note :The PopUp editor is initialized only once, when the Grid is created, using default model values. This is the reason for the current behavior - the default value of the List is null. The editor templates itself are bound via MVVM, which is why they display the correct model value when the PopUp is opened for each Grid item.

**But what would be the work around ?**

Comment: You've shortened you code too much. It's hard to understand what is what, like, where is your `EditRegistration`? I mean, i know that it is that razor code, but where it is located? How are you using the Model on it ? It is probably an empty Model in that context, that is why you're getting an empty list.

Comment: Are you passing any model into the template?

Comment: What I do for Master/Detail situations is embed another kendo control like a listbox or grid and populate it via an ajax call (DataSource > Read > ("GetBatteries", "Controller", new {id = parentId }). Or you can do something like [this](https://www.telerik.com/forums/pass-grid-view-model-data-to-editor-template) to get the parent id.